# Is it possible to book international tickets without passport?

Tags: passports, international-travel

We are in the process of applying for our passports. Given the long wait time of 8 weeks in US, we would like to book international tickets, before prices go up too high. Is there a way to book international tickets without passport? If the answer is airline specific, let's use United as example. Thanks.